# Flaskr tutorial ModuleNotFoundError No module named Flaskr

Tags: python, flask

I am going through the flask tutorial up to the [Test Coverage](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/tests/) section.
And after finishing writing all the test files listed in the tutorial documentation I get the following error.

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/Desktop/flask_tutoriel/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:5: in <module>
    from flaskr import create_app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskr'
```

1. Could you help me understand why this error?
   Because the module is as you can see in the project tree image.

[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7gNM.png)

**Conftest.py**

```
import os
import tempfile

import pytest
from flaskr import create_app
from flaskr.db import get_db, init_db

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.sql'), 'rb') as f:
    _data_sql = f.read().decode('utf8')


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    db_fd, db_path = tempfile.mkstemp()

    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True,
        'DATABASE': db_path,
    })

    with app.app_context():
        init_db()
        get_db().executescript(_data_sql)

    yield app

    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(db_path)


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()

class AuthActions(object):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self._client = client

    def login(self, username='test', password='test'):
        return self._client.post(
            '/auth/login',
            data={'username': username, 'password': password}
        )

    def logout(self):
        return self._client.get('/auth/logout')


@pytest.fixture
def auth(client):
    return AuthActions(client)
```

**Tree of the test folder**

```
 tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── data.sql
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── conftest.cpython-39-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
    ├── test_auth.py
    ├── test_blog.py
    ├── test_db.py
    └── tests_factory.py
```

Comment: Have you already run `pip install -e .` to install it in editable mode?

Comment: same pb here, even after running `pip install -e .` The answer by @thga solved it for me seems like a path issue

Answer (score 1):

That means that you haven't installed the module. Try uninstalling the package using `pip uninstall flaskr` then re-installing it with `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why but this worked for me.

```
python -m pytest
```

It was found [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2908)

I hope it helps.